# Не могу сделать UPDATE jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, update

проблема заключается с обновлением данных:
Есть запрос insert, плюс метод который генерирует рандомный первичный ключ uuid :

```
public void insert(Client obj) {

      obj.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
      String sql = "INSERT INTO Client (id,name,surname,middleName,insurancePolicy,phoneNumber) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      sqlCommand(obj, sql);
  }
```

Есть запрос на update:

```
@Override
    public void update(Client obj) {
        String sql = "UPDATE Client Set name = ?  , surname = ? ,middleName = ? , insurancePolicy =?,  phoneNumber = ?, WHERE id=" + obj.getId() + ";";
        sqlCommandR(obj, sql);
    }
```

Запрос выполнения в который падают все добавления и обновления. но проблема в том, что когда делаю update, то в методе sqlCommand записывается getId(), но он уже есть в update и должен остаться старым. В общем когда обновляю запрос получаю:

`NullPointerException на строке метода sqlCommand: preparedStatement.setObject(1, obj.getId());`

```
private void sqlCommand(Client obj, String sql) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = BaseConnect.preparedStatement(sql);
                preparedStatement.setObject(1, obj.getId());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, obj.getName());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, obj.getSurname());
                preparedStatement.setString(4, obj.getMiddleName());
                preparedStatement.setLong(5, obj.getInsurancePolicy());
                preparedStatement.setLong(6, obj.getPhoneNumber());
            preparedStatement.execute();
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Не могу понять в чем причина...

Comment: `sqlCommandR` - что за метод?  или это опечатка в названии?

Comment: Уберите запятую после phoneNumber = ?. Что касается NullPointerExcepiton - у вас либо BaseConnect.preparedStatement(sql) возвращает null, либо obj является null.

Comment: sqlComandR и phoneNumber - это опечатки здесь, в коде все правильно. Посмотрел в отладчике - preparedStatement =null, но что проверить теперь?

Comment: А можно ли генерировать UUID значение при создании таблицы,  например:     " id UUID NOT NULL IDENTITY RANDOM_UUID(),\n" +

Comment: Дальше проверять метод `BaseConnect.preparedStatement`, почему он возвращает `null`.